# Nonautonomous wave equation of memory type

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-and-monoids, linear-pde, hyperbolic-pde

I want to apply the semigroup approach of nonautonomous evolution equation for the following wave equation
$$u'' - \Delta u + \int\limits_0^t {g(s)} \Delta u(s)ds = 0$$
This problem can be written under the standard form of Cauchy problem
$$U' = A(t)U$$
where$$
A(t)=\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ 
\Delta -\int_{0}^{t}g(s)\Delta ds & 0%
\end{array}%
\right) 
$$
 It is obvious that we can't apply the classical semigroups approach because the operator $A$ in this case depends on $t$. I tried to find some references which talk about these things but I didn't secceed. I want from you some advice or halp. Thank you.